# Click to open modal and send code

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a scenario here.  I have a set of records with diferent Ids that when clicked open a modal window.  This modal window has a form that is filled and submitted.  My problem is I need to add the Id of the item that was initially clicked to open the modal to the form results as hidden field.  I have done

The link below triggers the modal pop

```
<a class="modal-with-form btn btn-default getPlan" data-id="@item.PlanId" id="@item.PlanId" data-target="#modalForm" href="#modalForm">Sign Up Now</a>
```

I have this script below that should Ideally send the id to the modal but for some reason it does not work

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".getPlan ", function ($) {
var myPlanId = $(this).data('id');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(".well.container #pid").val(myPlanId));
                });
```

The modal dialog with the form is enclosed in a `div class "well container"`
I really am at a miss since I have used this strategy to work on a bootstrap modal scenario but this works on some other javascript plugin.

Failing on this, I was looking at another scenario where I could send the pId to my controller Asynchronously when the modal is activated through ajax.  If I am able to do this, then I will save the pId in `session` or `ViewData` and use it as a hack.

I tried the script below that nothing happens

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).on("click", ".getPlan ", function ($) {

                var myArticleId = $(this).data('id');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(".well.container #sid").val(myArticleId));
            });

          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Article/",
           data: myArticleId,
           datatype: "html",
           success: function (data) {
               $('#result').html(data);
           }
       });

            </script>
```

Please help

Comment: The first approach should work. Are you sure there's only one `#pid`in your document?

Comment: Yes it is only I have crossed checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to maintain a div with display:none in your modal with a class say "mymodal".
Now try to get the id you would like to pass to modal by searching for it in parents div of getPlan too. I think var myArticleId = $(this).data('id'); is not giving the correct id. You can use something like $(this).parents("theclasshere").text(). Then we can simply use this id in the modal by $(".mymodal").text(myArtivleId).

It is always better to have the id into modal in the view itself. Try not to get the id from controller. It would not be an efficient way. I seriously doubt if you are gettin the correct id in myArtcileId

Comment: thanks.  can you elaborate further for me am not that good with Javascript.